# combine lists on index in R

Tags: r, list, purrr

I have two lists:

```
# agg blocks don't need methods
list_1 <- list(
  foo = list(list(txt = "MEAN", val= "NONE")),
  foo = list(list(txt = "MEAN", val= "Week 54")),
  foo = list(list(txt = "FREQ", df= "df"))
)

# 
list_2 <- list(
  foo = list(list(txt = "TEXT", df = "df_1")),
  foo = list(list(txt = "SAMPLE ", df = "df_2")),
  foo = list(list(txt = "OTHER", df = "df_1"))
)
```

How do I create a third list that appends the `val`s from `list_1` into `list_2`

## Desired Output

```
list_3 <- list(
  foo = list(list(txt = "TEXT", df = "df_1", val = "NONE")),
  foo = list(list(txt = "SAMPLE ", df = "df_2", val = "Week 54")),
  foo = list(list(txt = "OTHER", df = "df_1"))
)
```

```
$foo
$foo[[1]]
$foo[[1]]$txt
[1] "TEXT"

$foo[[1]]$df
[1] "df_1"

$foo[[1]]$val
[1] "NONE"



$foo
$foo[[1]]
$foo[[1]]$txt
[1] "SAMPLE "

$foo[[1]]$df
[1] "df_2"

$foo[[1]]$val
[1] "Week 54"



$foo
$foo[[1]]
$foo[[1]]$txt
[1] "OTHER"

$foo[[1]]$df
[1] "df_1"
```

Please note some list elements are missing `val` but the two lists will always be the same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a nested `Map`.  Loop over the outer `list` with `Map`, then extract the 'val' component from the `inner` `list` and assign it to the corresponding element of second `list`

```
out <- Map(function(lst1, lst2) Map(c, lst2, val =
         lapply(lst1, `[[`, 'val')), list_1, list_2)
```

-checking with OP's expected

```
all.equal(out, list_3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This works and I can probably figure it out from here, but I wanted to only bring over the `val` element to list_2 (as opposed to your method where each element in the list now has two $txt for example)

Comment: @MayaGans can you please check